# Update oxyplot model from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, oxyplot

It's my first time I using WPF and I have a problem.
I can't update my oxyplot model from another thread.
I can draw point in not another thread, but when I'm trying to do so in another nothing happens.
Now I have this code:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        doComputingThread compute = new doComputingThread();
        Thread _MainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(compute.MainThread));
        _MainThread.Start();
    }

class doComputingThread{
   public doComputingThread()
    {
        DataPlot = new PlotModel();
        DataPlot.Series.Add(new LineSeries());
    }
    public void MainThread()
    {
        bool flag;

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 10;
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { GuiRefresher(true); };
        _timer.Enabled = true;

        Thread _ComputeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProducerThread));
        _ComputeThread.Start();
    }
    public void ProducerThread()
    {
        //populate queue

        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;

        for (double t = 0; t < 2 * 3.14; t = t + 0.1)
        {
            X = (int)(Math.Cos(t) * 5000);
            Y = (int)(Math.Sin(t) * 5000);


            Coordinate.X = X;
            Coordinate.Y = Y;
            _queue.Enqueue(Coordinate);
        }
    public void GuiRefresher(object flag)
    {

        if (_queue.TryDequeue(out Coordinate))
        {
            //this part didn't refresh my oxyplot
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
           {
               (DataPlot.Series[0] as LineSeries).Points.Add(new DataPoint(Coordinate.X, Coordinate.Y));
               DataPlot.InvalidatePlot(true);
           });
```

}

All working as expected except the part when `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. I didn't understand why my plot didn't refresh.

I have some idea that I don't understand what thread is UI thread in this case with WPF and maybe I should initiate my threads in `doComputingThread` constructor.

Xaml:

```
<ui:WslMainWindow x:Class="fpga_control.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:fpga_control"
    xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Keysight.Ccl.Wsl.UI;assembly=Keysight.Ccl.Wsl"
    xmlns:DynamicVectorImages="clr-namespace:Keysight.Ccl.Wsl.UI.Controls.DynamicVectorImages;assembly=Keysight.Ccl.Wsl" 
    Title="Example 1 (WPF)" Height="461.311" Width="621.393">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid >
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding DataPlot}" Margin="10,10,152,0" Height="418" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="464,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="137" Height="38" RenderTransformOrigin="0.303,1.929" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="468,53,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code appears to be adding the same co-ordinate to the queue in the loop. You're not creating a new `Coordinate` instance each time during the loop.

Also your `_queue.TryDequeue(out Coordinate)` line produces a syntax error for me as it's trying to use `Coordinate` as a variable rather than a class.

Without the definition for `Coordinate` I can't confirm any of this.

Also, **I cannot see where you've actually added your `DataPlot` to your form or any control on your form.** It just doesn't appear that you're displaying anything in any case.

The bottom-line is that your example code isn't a minimal, complete and verifiable example. So I can only guess at what the issues are.

I am going to give you an alternative that I think will give you what you want.

To start with I'm providing a simple definition for `Coordinate`:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

Now I'm going to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework to do all of the threading, computation, and dispatching of your code - here's how I would write the `Button_Click` handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataPlot = new PlotModel();
    DataPlot.Series.Add(new LineSeries());

    int steps = 60;
    IObservable<Coordinate> query =
        Observable
            .Generate(
                0,
                n => n < steps,
                n => n + 1,
                n => n * 2.0 * Math.PI / steps,
                n => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10.0))
            .Select(t => new Coordinate()
            {
                X = (int)(Math.Cos(t) * 5000),
                Y = (int)(Math.Sin(t) * 5000),
            });

    IDisposable subscription =
        query
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(c =>
            {
                (DataPlot.Series[0] as LineSeries).Points.Add(new DataPoint(c.X, c.Y));
                DataPlot.InvalidatePlot(true);
            });
}
```

With this code you no longer need your `doComputingThread` class at all.

The `Observable.Generate` code produces the `t` values for the `60` data-points that your original code produced, but it does so only one value at a time every `10.0` milliseconds. This code is effectively a timer and the producer of the `t` steps.

The `.Select` maps the `t` value to a `Coordinate` value.

The `subscription` is the execution of the `query`. The first step is to marshall the values back to the UI thread with the `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` call and then the `.Subscribe` takes each value and runs the `c => ...` delegate on the UI thread.

This should update the plot nicely.

If you want to stop the plotting early just call `subscription.Dispose()` and it will stop.

You need to NuGet "System.Reactive" and "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading" to get the bits. You will also need the following `using` statements to get the code to compile:

```
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```

Just don't forget - you still need to add the `DataPlot` to your form somehow.